# Which dynamixel package shoud be used?

Tags: ros, dynamixel, robotis

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone have experience with both "dynamixel_motor" and ("dynamixel_sdk" or "dynamixel_workbench")
If I am understanding correctly, it seems that "dynamixel_motor" has long been the package ROS community has been using.
However, now there is an official package from ROBOTIS called "dynamixel_sdk" and "dynamixel_workbench"? But, it does not yet seem popular.

I am leaning toward the official package because it is official package but does it have all capabilities of "dynamixel_motor" package? Has anybody tried these new official packages? Any thoughts on which package I should start with for my motors (MX-12W)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261887/which-dynamixel-package-shoud-be-used?/) by [jys](https://answers.ros.org/users/3404/jys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 212 on 2017-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROBOTIS has started ROS supports in earnest last year. We have many useful packages and maintain its every day.

The [dynamixel_sdk](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_sdk) is a ROS wrapper for the ROBOTIS Dynamixel SDK. It is a software development library that provides Dynamixel control functions(like "sync_write") for packet communication. It is designed for Dynamixel actuators using protocol 1.0(AX, RX, MX, PRO) or protocol 2.0(X series(It is NEW series!!)). Moreover, it supports all programming languages used by ROS(C++, Python).

The [dynamixel_workbench](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_workbench) is developed by using "dynamixel_sdk". ''single_manager'' shows Dynamixel status using ROS Topic and it can helps access all control tables of Dynamixel in terminal and even GUI("single_manager_gui"). So, anyone can change ID, Baudrate, Operating Mode and other data in ROS. (We have been developing "dynamixel_manager" in Linux version. It will be showed soon.) "dynamixel_workbench_controller" and "dynamixel_workbench_tutorial" are showed how to use "dynamixel_sdk" in ROS. It supports how to launch Dynamixel actuators have different operating mode. ROS user who want to use Dynamixel for their platform can use this packages.

"dynamixel_motor" is compact and user-friendly package and it has been supporting Dynamixel in ROS. We are grateful for maintainer who helps our products.

Nowadays, ROBOTIS supports ROS. "dynamixel_sdk" and "dynamixel_workbench" provide software for all Dynamixel actuator and its are updated every day. After using our nice packages, please feel free to give feedback or question. We are ready to any issues. Thanks :)

---

Originally posted by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) with karma: 811 on 2017-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So far I haven't figured out what are differences between two package suites. On the official Robotis repo I even [asked a similar question](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/DynamixelSDK/issues/26).
Given that [dynamixel_motor](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_motor)'s maintenance has gone stale unfortunately, your best bet might be to try the official one as long as it suites your need.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-05-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jys](https://answers.ros.org/users/3404/jys/) on 2017-05-17**:
Thanks for your answer. Do you know if all these things listed here in dynamixel_controllers (dynamixel_motor) tutorials are possible to do with dynamixel_workbench packages?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-05-17**:
I don't know since I no longer use the motor at the moment, but sounds like the manufacturer takes this interest seriously. See (and maybe continue discussion in) the linked ticket.

**Comment by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) on 2017-05-17**:
Yes. dynamixel_workbench packages supports all functions has dynamixel_motor.

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2017-08-11**:
Great information; thanks!  Does dynamixel_sdk  provide any other advantage over  dynamixel_motors, in terms of performance or features? I'm already using  dynamixel_motors without any problem, so it's anyway worth doing the effort of porting to  dynamixel_sdk? Thanks